# Is it OK to have an empty anchor tag?

Tags: html, css

I know that I can do the following if I want to turn an image into a click-able link:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/username"><img src="icons/twitter.png" /></a>
```

But I would prefer to use a CSS background image so that I can have a hover state:

```
<a class="twitter" href="http://twitter.com/username"></a>

# css
.twitter{display:block; width:16px; height:16px; background:url("twitter.png")}
```

This works fine except I'm not sure it's entirely valid to have an anchor link that contains nothing. Chrome renders it fine, as does FF, but I'm not sure if others are the same.

I realise I could just put some text inside the link, and hide it with `text-indent: -9999px`, but I've never liked that approach, for [various](http://luigimontanez.com/2010/stop-using-text-indent-css-trick/) [reasons](http://maileohye.com/html-text-indent-not-messing-up-your-rankings/). Is my code above cross-browser compatible?

Comment: your `<a>` tag only gets the style provided by the `.twitter`? or does it have some kind of reset with additional styles?

Comment: In HTML3 this was a common thing `<a name = "foo"><!-- --></a>`, but I don't know how modern browsers treat that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's valid, but it's best if you did put something in there and used something like

```
font-size: 0;
```

to hide it away. This way, if someone does not have CSS (screen readers for example), he would still be able to tell approximately what the link is about.

**[Here's a great article on the subject](http://css-tricks.com/css-image-replacement/)**

Comment: Or `font-size: 0;`, perhaps, but any relative sizing based on `em` units would likely be affected badly by that.

Comment: @DavidThomas: Which is why I said "something like" There are several solutions :)

Comment: Or any of the various image replacement techniques: http://css-tricks.com/css-image-replacement/

Comment: @Truth: yeah, there are absolutely other alternatives; it's just that the OP specifically stated his dislike of the `text-indent` approach; though my comment was merely meant to suggest an alternative, rather than criticise your own.

Comment: @DavidThomas: Didn't see that one. Edited :D

Comment: thanks, this is a nice solution, thanks for the css-tricks link too

Comment: there is no need for css tricks, if you want an empty anchor, leave it empty or put a whitespace inside.

Comment: @JaimeOlivares: What would that do for screen readers? Or people that don't have CSS enabled? Websites are meant for **content**, not **pretty**.

Comment: @Truth, please enlight me and tell me in what scenario you have not CSS enabled. Any modern page design relies on the fact that CSS is enabled, unless the page is **explicitly** designed for that case. For screen readers a space is nothing.

Comment: @JaimeOlivares: Umm, no. When a **professional** makes web pages, he makes sure that his pages are **usable** and **readable** with 0 CSS or JavaScript enabled. The point that for screen readers a space is nothing, only proves my point. Someone with a screen reader won't be able to tell what's on the link.

Comment: @JaimeOlivares Pages don't rely on CSS at all. The **design** may rely on CSS, but the content of the site is just text at the basic level. Web professionals might not agree with the edge cases, but a major difference between novice web developers/designers and the seasoned ones is a basic understanding of progressive enhancement.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha keep in mind hiding site content, especially links, is frowned upon by Google as possible negative actions.

Comment: This isn't hiding. If google can see it's `font-size: 0` then they can also see it's `height: whatever; width: whatever` and has a background image.

Answer (score 8):

It is not OK at all, since it breaks fundamental accessibility principles. There is no way to specify alternative text for a background image, the same way you can and should specify it using an `alt` attribute in an `img` tag for a content image. See WCAG 2.0 [Guideline 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG/#text-equiv).

If you wish to change an image on mouseover, there are CSS and JavaScript techniques for that.

Answer (score 4):

It is perfectly valid, but if you want, you can put a blank space inside: `&nbsp`;

Answer (score 2):

Use &nbsp; as the text, and you are good.

Comment: See comments on my answer above on why that's a bad practice to do.

Answer (score 1):

Over at Markup.tips we recently did some accessibility testing in iOS 8 and discovered that VoiceOver will not navigation to empty links. There must at least be a non-breaking space. Whether this should be considered an iOS bug or not we are not sure.